# Evaluate a Range and Write in Another Column Based on a Row Entry

Tags: vba, excel

I want to look in a range and find flag certain values, then populate the same row in another column based on those values.

```
Column 1       Column 2
Code1
Code10
```

If I specify Code1 in the macro, I want to populate column 2.

I have the following code. I get a runtime error. How can I avoid a runtime error.

```
Sub Test()

With Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set r = .Range("A:A").Find(what:="Old", LookIn:=xlValues)
    Dim rownum As Long
    rownum = r.Row
    Dim rownum2 As Long
    rownum2 = rownum - 1

    With Sheets("Sheet1")

        Set r2 = .Range("C6:C" & rownum2)
        Dim cell As Variant

        For Each cell In r2
           If Cells.Value = ("Code1" Or "Code2" Or "Code3" Or "Code4") Then
                .Select
                .Offset(0, 7).Value = "Special"
            End If
        Next cell

    End With

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Do all declarations on top. I guess it's not necessary to have with statement, generally to do operation on same item with used.you Google on usage of with

Comment: Have check of why two with statement for sheet1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleaned it up a little:

```
Sub Test()
Dim r2 As Range
Dim rownum2 As Long
Dim cell As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    rownum2 = .Range("A:A").Find(what:="Old", LookIn:=xlValues).Row - 1
    Set r2 = .Range("C6:C" & rownum2)
End With

For Each cell In r2
    If cell.Value = "Code1" Or cell.Value = "Code2" Or cell.Value = "Code3" Or cell.Value = "Code4" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = "Special"
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

The main issue was the If statement.  See above for the proper method of using the `Or` statement.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much.